# Comparing text on two different worksheets

Tags: excel-formula

Worksheet 1 has text in Column A,  I want to see if that same text is in a range of cells on worksheet 2,  If yes return with *, if no leave blank.

Comment: You want countif inside an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

**This is very simple to do.**
We are making the following assumptions.

```
Worksheet 1 = Sheet1
Worksheet 2 = Sheet2
```

the following formula will do what you desire.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1)>0,"*","")
```

How it works...  Countifs searches thru Sheet2 Column A for data in Sheet1, Cell A1, and counts each time it encounters that data.  The IF statement evaluates the count to see if it is greater than 0, if it is, then we return a * (star), otherwise we return nothing (blank).